# Running multiple jobs: a combination of parallel and serial

Tags: bash, parallelism

I would like to run tasks a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2, c_1, c_2 in the following fashion:
a_i, b_j, c_k (where i, j, k are 0 or 1) can be run in parallel. But a_2 should be run right after a_1 completion (they use the same resources so a_2 should wait for a_1 to free the resources). Same with b, c.

How can I do this in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
( a_1; a_2 ) &
( b_1; b_2 ) &
( c_1; c_2 ) &
wait
```

This would run three background jobs and then wait for all to finish.  Each of the three background jobs would run its commands one after the other.

For a slightly more complicated variation:

```sh
for task in a b c; do
    for num in 1 2; do "${task}_$num"; done &
done
wait
```

This would do the same thing, but would construct the strings `a_1`, `a_2` etc. and then execute the tasks resulting from generating these strings as commands.  This would obviously only work if your tasks are actual commands with these names.

Comment: Very clear response. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel:

```
parallel {1}_{2} ::: a b c ::: 0 1
parallel {}_2 ::: a b c
```

Alternatively:

```
parallel '{}_0; {}_1; {}_2' ::: a b c
```